# What does 'reveal his Son in me' convey of Paul's experience ? Galatians 1:15,16

Tags: word-study, paul, galatians

> οτε δε ευδοκησεν ο θεος ο αφορισας με εκ κοιλιας μητρος μου και καλεσας δια της χαριτος αυτου
>
> αποκαλυψαι τον υιον αυτου εν εμοι ινα ευαγγελιζωμαι αυτον εν τοις εθνεσιν ευθεως ου προσανεθεμην σαρκι και αιματι
>
> Galatians 1:15 and 16, TR (undisputed)
>
> But when it pleased God, who separated me from my mother's womb, and called me by his grace,
>
> **To reveal his Son in me**, that I might preach him among the heathen; immediately I conferred not with flesh and blood:
>
> Galatians 1:15 and 16, KJV

As Paul develops his argument towards the Galatian churches he states his own calling and his own experience.

What is the meaning of 'reveal' - αποκαλυψαι - his Son ?

What does he mean by the revelation being 'in' - εν εμοι - himself ?

This cannot refer, only, to a taught knowledge from an exterior source. If the knowledge of Christ were only a knowledge that is accumulated through reading, or through human teaching, then there were no need of 'revelation' by God. And no need of an 'inward' revelation.

What did Paul experience ? What is he conveying by this expression ?

Clearly, from his words, he is informing us what occurred to him. So this is not a matter of opinion, not a matter of speculation that we must guess at what he experienced. His words are intended to inform us about what was his inward reception of divine influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gal 1:16 is quintessentially Pauline pithiness.  But first the OP's excellent question.

The verb ἀποκαλύπτω (apokaluptó) means (BDAG) "**to cause something to be fully known, *reveal, disclose, bring to light, make fully known***".  The thing revealed here is "the Son", namely Jesus.  This was the direct fulfilment of the Jesus' own pronouncement on the road to Damascus recorded in Acts 9:15, *"Go!" said the Lord. "This man is My chosen instrument to carry My name before the Gentiles and their kings, and before the people of Israel.*

Paul was well educated and chose his (few) words carefully.  Note that in Gal 1:16, Paul says that the Son was to be revealed "in me" (ἐν ἐμοὶ).  Some versions translate this (incorrectly) as, "to me" rather than "in me".  The difference is important.

This essentially says that God chose Paul and his life experience to reveal Himself to the world - it was supremely effective!  Within three days, Paul went from great persecutor to great promulgator.  Part of his success was the effect that God's grace had produced: a huge, conspicuous change in Paul's life for the better.

Now it is true that Paul's Damascus road experience resulted in Jesus revealing Himself **to** Paul, but the main purpose was to reveal Jesus to the world via Paul by revealing God's grace **in** the life of Paul.  He discussed the effect of God's grace on the life a Christian, and it dramatic change it produces in Gal 2:4-10 and many other places.

Peter also understood this idea as recorded in 1 Peter 2:9, 12

> But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, God’s
>   special possession, that you may express the praises of him who called
>   you out of darkness into his wonderful light … Live such good lives
>   among the pagans that, though they accuse you of doing wrong, they may
>   see your good deeds and glorify God on the day he visits us.